# How to use <pre> tag to don't appear in the source code

Tags: php, html, pre

I would like to render a webpage like the pastebin.com does in a raw view mode.
Here is an example on pastebin.com

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VawEm8ge

if you look to the source code, there is no html code.

I tried in this way:

```
   <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
   #EXTM3U
   #EXTVLCOPT:udp-caching=1000
   #EXTINF:-1, DUNA Televízió
   http://212.40.98.166/intstreams/mtva/dunalive.smil/VID_854x480_HUN.m3u8

   #EXTINF:-1 , Duna World
   http://212.40.98.161/intstreams/mtva/dunaworldlive_international.smil/VID_854x480_HUN.m3u8
  </pre>
```

But the output is not the same with the output from the pastebin.com

Comment: that's because that's a (raw)text file, not html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because that page is not HTML. If you take a look at the response, the `Content-Type` is `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

To do the same thing on your sever, you need to control the response header to set `Content-Type`. For example:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Just set it before writing output.

Comment: I used now this and it is OK, Thank You
          `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`